# How to properly remove H2 from Grails

Tags: grails, configuration, h2

I am trying to minimalize my Grails (2.4.2) app and cull out a lot of stuff that `create-app` generates that I'm just not going to use.

One of these things is H2. I'm just not going to use it, and besides, if I needed an embedded DB, I'd prefer to use HSQLDB.

So I made the following changes to my `BuildConfig`:

```
...

// Remove the DB console for all environments, not just dev.
grails.dbconsole.enabled = false

...

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
        excludes 'h2'
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, when I do a `run-app`, I get the following error:

```
... <huge stacktrace omitted for brevity>
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: org.h2.Driver
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: org.h2.Driver
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    ... 4 more
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

What's going on and how do I fix this error *while* properly removing H2 and any of its configs/references?

---

#### Update, my DataSources.groovy file

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    //    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            properties {
                // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                maxActive = 50
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 10 * 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you remove the references to H2 from your DataSource.groovy file?

Comment: Thanks @Gregg (+1) - please see my update and follow up question underneath Donal's answer - I have the same question for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `grails-app/conf/DataSources.groovy` you probably have some references to the h2 Driver, e.g.

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
```

Remove the dataSource configuration completely if you're not using any DB. If you're using a different DB, replace the h2 driver class name with the class name of the driver for your DB.

Comment: Thanks @Donal (+1) - please see my update which includes my entire `DataSources.groovy` file. I am afraid to remove my `dataSource` config because I see other `h2` references in the file. I deally I'd like to get rid of `dataSources` completely because my Grails app will not have a DB (rather, it will depend on backing services for all persistence). Is it safe to remove **all** the content from this file? Or are there references to these other configs in other part of the project?

Comment: @unfettered I think you can remove all content from `DataSources.groovy`, perhaps even delete the file itself